# WordPress: permalink rewrite for custom post type category archive

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type `resource`. This custom post type shares the `category` taxonomy with posts.

For a given category term archive, example url: `/category/reducing-inequality/`, I want to have an additional URL that displays ONLY the resource custom post type for that category. I can do so by using a query string:

`category/reducing-inequality/?post_type=resource`

What I want to do though is create a rewrite rule that will have this category archive (the above URL) instead rewrite to `/resource/category/reducing-inequality`

Is this possible? Any guidance is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) is for. I'd do something like:

```
function custom_resource_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^(\w+)/category/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/?', 'category/$matches[2]/?post_type=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_resource_rewrite_rules');
```

You could, of course, pass `resource` to the rewrite directly...but the above is a more general solution that will work for any custom post type.

**Note:** You'll likely have to head to the WP-Admin and re-save your permalinks to properly "flush" them, in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response, rnevious– that doesn't seem to be working though. Going to this URL http://localhost:8888/wtg/category/reducing-inequality/?post_type=resource does not rewrite.

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks?

Comment: Yes I did– went to wp-admin/options-permalink.php, switched to default, then back to "post name"

Comment: Also, are you wanting to re-direct, or re-write the URLs? From your comment above, it seems like you want to redirect to the "pretty" URL if someone requests `http://localhost:8888/wtg/category/reducing-inequality/?post_type=resource`...My answers is in response to actual rewriting, not redirecting.

Comment: I guess I want to do both. How I should have phrased it is: I want this page: `/resource/category/reducing-inequality` to function (as a category archive for the resource post type) the same as this one `/category/reducing-inequality/?post_type=resource`

Comment: So I've posted about the first part, related to your post title (rewriting the URL)...You'll likely need to add a rule in .htaccess in order to handle the redirect.

Comment: Any idea on what that redirect in .htaccess would look like?